# How reuse properties in typesafe config files?

Tags: scala, properties, akka, config

Consider following files:

**application.conf**

```
app {
    port = 5000
}
```

**reference.conf**

```
akka {
    cluster {
        seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://sysName@localhost:"${app.port}]
    }
}
```

So when I run `ConfigFactory.load()` it fails, because `${app.port}` does not present in reference.conf.

But load algorithm is clear - `reference.conf` is loaded and merged with `application.conf`. Is there a way to load `application.conf` and "include" `reference.conf` into it?

**IMPORTANT**

I tried add `include "reference.conf"` at the first line in `application.conf` it does not help.

Comment: reference.conf is for libraries. You should put the akka.cluster.seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://sysName@localhost:"${app.port}] in your  application.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file("")` syntax to include file.

```
include file("reference.conf")
```

see https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#include-syntax

Comment: It is the same. as `include "reference.conf"`. Moreover when "include" omitted and `application.conf` is loaded it merges with `reference.conf` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

According to Typesafe Config [documentation](https://github.com/lightbend/config#note-about-resolving-substitutions-in-referenceconf-and-applicationconf):

> The implication of this is that the `reference.conf` stack has to be
>   self-contained; you can't leave an undefined value `${foo.bar}` to be
>   provided by `application.conf`, or refer to `${foo.bar}` in a way that you
>   want to allow `application.conf` to override. However, `application.conf`
>   can refer to a `${foo.bar}` in `reference.conf`.

The documentation also lists some possible workarounds:

> - putting an `application.conf` in a library jar, alongside the    `reference.conf`, with values intended for later resolution.
> - putting some logic in code instead of building up values in the config itself.